# Конвертация из PHP в C++

Tags: php, c++

Есть Фрагмент кода на PHP:

```
$classes = array ();
$links = array ();

$classes[0] = array ("Математика","Русский","История");
$classes[1] = array ("Математика","Литература","Физика");

$links[0] = array ("Математика" => 1,"Русский" => 2,"История" => 3)
$links[1] = array ("Математика" => 5,"Литература" => 2,"Физика" => 9);
```

Как это реализовать на C++?

Comment: Ключевые слова: массив, ассоциативный массив. Что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Присвоить строковому массиву значение.Так чтобы Они были связаны. К примеру Математике присвоить значение 1,а в дальнейшем я мог работать только с цифрой 1. В конце я меняю значение 1 на Математику

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустите, посмотрите, если непонятно, спрашивайте

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// здесь задается массив
string a[3] = {"Математика", "Русский", "Литература"};

// это количество элементов массива
int a_size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(string);

// это индекс массива
int i;

// проход по всем элементам массива и их печать
for (i = 0; i < a_size; i++)
cout << "Элемент массива c индексом " << i << " = " << a[i] << endl;

// если нужно как-то взаимодействовать с элементами массива
// обращайтесь к ним по индексу:

a[1] = "Физика"; // изменили значение второй ячейки

cout  << '\n' << "Элемент массива с индексом " << 1 << " теперь = " << a[1] 
<< endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В коде ниже предусматривается ситуация, когда заранее не известно сколько элементов будет записано в массивы.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// здесь задается массив
map<int, string> a;
a[0] = "Математика";
a[1] = "Русский";
a[2] = "Литература";
// это количество элементов массива
int size = a.size();

// проход по всем элементам массива и их печать
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
cout << "Элемент массива c индексом " << i << " = " << a[i] << endl;

// если нужно как-то взаимодействовать с элементами массива
// обращайтесь к ним по индексу:

a[1] = "Физика"; // изменили значение второй ячейки
a[5] = "Физ-культура"; //Дописать в переменную еще значений

cout  << '\n' << "Элемент массива с индексом " << 1 << " теперь = " << a[1] 
<< endl;

cout  << '\n' << "Элемент массива с индексом " << 5 << " теперь = " << a[5] 
<< endl;

return 0;
}
```

В C++ не предусмотрено создание массивов как в PHP, для этого есть соответствующие шаблоны: vector, map и т.д.

Рассмотрим данную строчку:

```
map<int, string> a;
```

Тут объявляется шаблон **map**, далее идут скобки **<>** в них вы указываете 2 типа переменных:

1. тип переменной которая будет ключем (в нашем случае это число)
2. тип переменной для хранения информации (в нашем случае это строка)

Рассмотрим пример:

```
map<int, int> numbers;
a[0] = 10000;
```

В данном примере мы создаем шаблон в переменной "numbers", где число будет ключем (индексом) для значения 10000.

```
cout << "Элемент шаблона numbers под номером 0 = " << a[0] << endl;
/* Вместо a[0] программа выведет 10000 */
```

Создавать шаблоны переменных можно с любым типом данных.

```
map<int, char> a;
map<float, string> a;
map<char, int> a
```

И так далее...

Comment: Стоит убрать `<stdio.h>` и использовать для размеров `std::size_t` вместо `int`